# Angular-UI ui-router supporting infinitely nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a situation in my Angular app where I'd like to consider an infinitely nested state/route.  For example, let's say that I have a person and I want to see the lineage of the family.  I might have routes that look like this:

```
/person/0
/person/0/child/1
/person/0/child/1/child/2
/person/0/child/1/child/2/child/3
```

And this could go on forever, as the user click further down the tree.  How does a route like this get defined using `ui-router`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to define your route and then parse the url to get the child id, like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('person', {
    url: '/person/:id',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'parentTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ParentCtrl'
        }
    }
}).state('child', {
    url: '/person/:id/{path:.*}',
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        // params.path contains something like `child/1/child/2`
        // so you get get the current child id like this
        var path = params.path.split('/').reverse(),
            childId = path[0];
        // for more flexibility you can retrieve all ids from the request and store them in $stateParams
        // so you can easily work with them in your controller

        // here you can write some logic to determine the right template
        return 'childTemplate.html';
    },
    controller: 'ChildCtrl'
});
```